# Exchange 2007 ResetSearchIndex.ps1 time

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007, time, search, full-text-search

I am relatively new to exchange. We are running Exchange 2007 sp2 for a medium/large institution and we are having trouble with OWA's search function not working.

I was going to try running ResetSearchIndex.ps1 but it looks like it needs to be run on off hours. How long of a process is this? I understand that it will vary depending on the size but is it more of a matter of hours or minutes?

Comment: Which search function (users, emails, what?) and define not working?  How large is your environment?  What is the topology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unanswerable. It may be minutes, or hours, or days. There's no way to know. The best you could do would be to read and follow this article in order to collect pre and post rebuild statistics that you can use in the future to "predict" how long a rebuild might take.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2012/06/25/establishing-exchange-content-index-rebuild-baselines-part-1.aspx

Comment: Thank you! That is what I was looking for: in depth documentation.

Comment: Glad to help...

Answer (score 0):

ResetSearchIndex.ps1 runs very quickly. I have run it during the day in an Exchange 2010 environment.